# Files/Images uploading in Android

Tags: java, android, image-uploading

Is there any library like "picasso" (except volley) which can be used for uploading files to remote server?
Or any simple method for uploading image.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will be helpful, I guess.
Using this library, you can also able to pass headers or upload the file using multiparts...
https://github.com/koush/ion